# send a websocket message in a route, Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, websocket

### The Goal:

Let's say we have a marketplace full of shops. I'm creating a specific page `localhost:3000/livePurchases/:storeId` for a shop owner to monitor live notifications of when they got a new purchase.

[image]

[image]

`alert('you received a new purchase')` should be triggered by a WebSocket when an item is purchased.

### The Problem:

I need to set up WebSockets on my express server so that the websocket can be triggered somewhere in my code different from where the websocket server was set up. But I don't understand how to do this.

The route `/newPurchase/:storeId` would be requested by the browser of a customer after they successfully purchase an item. The websocket should send a message within the code of the route `"/newPurchase/:storeId"` (backend) to the websocket on `"/livePurchases/:storeId"` (frontend) where the shop owner can monitor live purchases.

*`app.js`*

```js
const express = require("express");

module.exports = (config) => {
  const app = express();

  app.post("/newPurchase/:storeId", (req, res, next) => {
    const { storeId } = req.params;
    // trigger websocket message to `localhost:3000/livePurchases/:storeId`
    // when client requests this route

  });

  return app;
};
```

But app.js is exported and run from another script, `www.js`. In real scenarios this is to connect a database before running the app.:

*`www.js`*

```js
const app = require("../server/app")();

const port = process.env.PORT || "4000";
app.set("port", port);

app
  .listen(port)
  .on("listening", () =>
    console.log("info", `HTTP server listening on port ${port}`)
  );

module.exports = app;
```

So that means that the web socket server needs to be set up in `www.js`.

Below is a notifier service I got it from this [tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/solving-real-life-problems-in-javascript-sending-server-side-notifications-through-websockets-a3bdb2cc065), which seemed like it was trying to solve the problem I have, but it didn't explain how to implement it. It is a class that handles the websocket.

*`NotifierService.js`*

```js
const url = require("url");
const { Server } = require("ws");

class NotifierService {
  constructor() {
    this.connections = new Map();
  }

  connect(server) {
    this.server = new Server({ noServer: true });
    this.interval = setInterval(this.checkAll.bind(this), 10000);
    this.server.on("close", this.close.bind(this));
    this.server.on("connection", this.add.bind(this));
    server.on("upgrade", (request, socket, head) => {
      console.log("ws upgrade");
      const id = url.parse(request.url, true).query.storeId;

      if (id) {
        this.server.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) =>
          this.server.emit("connection", id, ws)
        );
      } else {
        socket.destroy();
      }
    });
  }

  add(id, socket) {
    console.log("ws add");
    socket.isAlive = true;
    socket.on("pong", () => (socket.isAlive = true));
    socket.on("close", this.remove.bind(this, id));
    this.connections.set(id, socket);
  }

  send(id, message) {
    console.log("ws sending message");

    const connection = this.connections.get(id);

    connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
  }

  broadcast(message) {
    console.log("ws broadcast");
    this.connections.forEach((connection) =>
      connection.send(JSON.stringify(message))
    );
  }

  isAlive(id) {
    return !!this.connections.get(id);
  }

  checkAll() {
    this.connections.forEach((connection) => {
      if (!connection.isAlive) {
        return connection.terminate();
      }

      connection.isAlive = false;
      connection.ping("");
    });
  }

  remove(id) {
    this.connections.delete(id);
  }

  close() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

module.exports = NotifierService;
```

### Where I left off implementing the `NotifierService`

I added the websocket server with the `NotifierService` in `www.js`

*`www.js with websockets added`*

```js
const app = require("../server/app")();
const NotifierService = require("../server/NotifierService.js");
const notifier = new NotifierService();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
notifier.connect(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || "4000";
app.set("port", port);

server
  .listen(port)
  .on("listening", () =>
    console.log("info", `HTTP server listening on port ${port}`)
  );

module.exports = app;
```

**But now how do I send the websocket message from the `/newPurchase` route in `app.js` on the backend?** If I create a new instance of `NotifierService` in `app.js` in order to use the `notifierService.send` method in the `/newPurchase` route, then the new `NotifierService` instance won't have access to the websocket connections because it would be a different instance than the one initiated on `www.js`.

**Front End:**

`App.js`

```js
import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LiveStorePurchases from "./LiveStorePurchases";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/livePurchases/:storeId">
            <LiveStorePurchases />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`LivePurchaseServer.js`

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function LiveStorePurchases() {
  let { storeId } = useParams();
  const URL = "ws://127.0.0.1:4000?storeId=" + storeId;

  const [ws, setWs] = useState(new WebSocket(URL));

  useEffect(() => {
    ws.onopen = (e) => {
      newFunction(e);

      function newFunction(e) {
        alert("WebSocket Connected");
      }
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      const message = e.data;
      alert(message);
    };

    return () => {
      ws.onclose = () => {
        alert("WebSocket Disconnected");
        setWs(new WebSocket(URL));
      };
    };
  }, [ws.onmessage, ws.onopen, ws.onclose, ws, URL]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        color: "red",
        fontSize: "4rem",
      }}
    >
      store: {storeId}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: First off, is the `/newPurchase/:storeId` route being sent from Javascript in your web page?  If not and it's a regular form post, then you can't send to a webSocket in that page anyway because the page will reload and it will have a new/different webSocket connection.

Comment: The request to the `localhost:4000/newPurchase/:storeId` route would come from a page where a customer checks out to indicate that a purchase was made. I wouldn't be sending any websocket messages back to that checkout page. I would be sending the websocket message to a different page that the owner of the shop may be monitoring- `localhost:3000/livePurchases/:storeId`. So the message would be  initiated in the code of the route `/newPurchase/:storeId` but it would be sent to the page `/livePurchases/:storeId`.

Comment: Then you need to find some way on the server to store any webSocket socket or sockets that belongs to a store owner so you can iterate through them and send a message on them.  Presumably you'd be monitoring incoming webSockets connections, figure out which ones belong to a store owner and save them somewhere and also be monitoring disconnects and removing them from the stored list (if they were in that list).

Comment: If you use socket.io instead of plain webSocket, this would be a perfect application for their "rooms" concept where you would add a store owner to a room when they connect and you can then broadcast to any connections in that room at any time from anywhere in the server with `io.to(someRoomName).emit(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I understand sending it to the websocket associated with the correct user is part of the process too. I'll need to figure that out. I think the tutorial I posted sort of addresses that. However the part I'm stuck on now is how do I access the websocket instance in the post request? Because it was created in www.js: `const notifier = new NotifierService();.... notifier.connect(server)`. How to I access it in app.js?

Comment: You have to export something (probably a function) from a module that keeps track of the webSocket connections that can be called from your route.  It's about importing and exporting things so one module can call into another module.

Comment: I was able to move the websocket instance to `app.js` instead of `www.js`. That made it so I could pass the websocket instance around to other routes so I could send messages from those routes. I posted my solution. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

**`app.js`**:

I was able to move the websocket instance to `app.js` instead of `www.js`. Then I simply passed that instance around to other routes.

```js
const express = require("express");
const NotifierService = require("../server/NotifierService.js");
const notifier = new NotifierService();
const http = require("http");
const routes = require("./routes");

module.exports = (config) => {
  const app = express();
  const server = http.createServer(app); // websocket created
  notifier.connect(server);              // and connected here in app.js

  //   I moved POST /newPurchase to routes.js in order
  //   to demonstrate how the notifier instance can be
  //   passed around to different routes
  app.use(routes(notifier));

  return server;
};
```

**`routes.js`:**

I created a routes file `routes.js` to show that
you could move the notifier instance around and call it from any route.

```js
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

// I moved "/newPurchase/:id" to this routes.js file to show that
// I could move the notifier instance around.

module.exports = (webSocketNotifier) => {
  router.post("/newPurchase/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    webSocketNotifier.send(req.params.id, "purchase made");
    res.status(200).send();
  });
  return router;
};
```

**`www.js`**:

```js
const server = require("../server/app")();

const port = process.env.PORT || "4000";

server
  .listen(port)
  .on("listening", () =>
    console.log("info", `HTTP server listening on port ${port}`)
  );

module.exports = server;
```